# Why does my mesh deform when i apply automatic weights?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, error, parent

I have a 3D model of a character I want to rig. I already created the rig and it matches the model pose, but whenever I press the automatic weights option it deforms drastically.
[image: Before automatic weights]

[image: After automatic weights]

Comment: Try to check in the "Keep Transform" checkbox in the bottom left, see if it helps

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots How can i do that. It says i can't, the file has to be smaller than 30 mb.

Comment: @Tsybe nothing changed.

Comment: Use another platform like workupload

Comment: @moonboots https://workupload.com/file/eVv36cPUVLn here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your armature's rest pose, it doesn't match the character's shapes, your character should be in T pose as well, if you parent your current object to this armature, then give it the pose you show, the object will be completely deformed by the pose. It's not the current pose of the armature that is taken into account when you parent but its rest pose:

[image]

So the solution is probably to give your character object a T pose as well. To do so you could try to correct the object with the armature: Duplicate your object and armature, apply the scale and rotation of your object and armature, apply the current armature pose as rest pose (image below), parent the object to the armature, change the bones position and rotation so that the object takes the T pose, apply the armature modifier, parent the object to the original armature (the one that has kept the default T pose):

[image]

Comment: It worked :)). Thanks